# Good BNF grammar tutorial / introduction for a beginner?

Tags: context-free-grammar, parser-generator, bnf

What's your tip for an introduction to BNF grammar (and how to use them in practice)?

Something concise with many examples would be great. Have been googling but only found enormously long artcles with unclear examples so far :/

(In my particular case, I'm trying to parse the [Galaxy Toolconfig syntax](https://bitbucket.org/galaxy/galaxy-central/wiki/ToolConfigSyntax), which includes if/else statements etc.)

Comment: I basically need to convert some if/else clauses into some internal structure in my Java App, so I thought some Grammar would be helpful. Though, eventhough it might not be required right now, I'm generally very much interested to learn some BNF stuff, since I have a strong feeling I'll need it sooner or later in the projects I'm working with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've always found the abnf rfc very good when regarding these issues: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2234.txt

Comment: Ah, thanks, looks good! That also lead me to a newer version of the documents, with some links to pdf version etc: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234

Comment: indeed, they are not the same. just pointed it out as a place to get started using something based on abnf. you might want (later on) start to get into the details of ebnf and bnf themselves

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Big thanks! Printed it out, to read it carefully! :)